# How to install kernel 4.0 on Freya?

Tags: software-installation, kernel

I'm using elementary Freya.

Is there any way to upgrade the Linux kernel to 4.0?

And by upgrading kernel can we download and install packages from elementary ppa ?

Comment: In your last sentence, do you mean “can we upgrade the kernel by installing a PPA?”, or “if I upgrade the kernel, will that let me use PPAs”, or something else?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the advantages of using the 4.0 kernel?

Comment: @waldyrious power Improvements, hardware improvements, new drivers and performance tweaks and so on.

Comment: @Gilles i mean “if I upgrade the kernel, will that let me use PPAs”

Comment: @Saeed Ok, then to answer that: no, upgrading the kernel will not have any impact on your ability to use PPAs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Access the Ubuntu kernel PPA mainline repository [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1-unstable/).
2. Download the following:

   ```
   linux-headers-4.1.0-040100-generic_4.1.0-040100.201506220235_<infrastructure>.deb
   linux-headers-4.1.0-040100_4.1.0-040100.201506220235_all.deb
   linux-image-4.1.0-040100-generic_4.1.0-040100.201506220235_<infrastructure>.deb
   ```
3. `cd` into the download directory and run

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

On reboot your system should boot the latest kernel. You can test this by running `uname -r`. Note that this will **not** automatically update from this point forward (in particular, you won't get any security fixes), and that this is not supported by elementary.

As for your question about PPAs: installing a newer kernel will not change anything about your ability to use PPAs.

Comment: He asked for 4.0. I wouldn't try on 4.1 just yet. Other than that, yes try the above instructions.