# Is it possible to install a more up-to-date kernel in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, kernel, updates

I would like to install a more recent kernel, as of now I have linux-image-3.16, and I would like to upgrade to 3.19 to achieve better compatibility (here's to hoping my GPU/motherboard fans will work as expected). However, when instaling linux-headers and linux-image 3.19, after rebooting I get a blank screen at the end of the boot sequence, when I was supposed to reach the login screen. The system completely hangs, and I can't reach the text consoles.

Is this doable? I'd love to be able to keep a more recent kernel, without having to ditch Freya because my fans don't work. On Luna this was almost effortless and had no issues doing it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Further info:
Freya running on Lenovo y510p, Core i7, 16GB RAM, SSD and Nvidia SLI with Nvidia privative driver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**System Recovery**

If you are now unable to boot, press (or tap) <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting (right after BIOS post screen) to show the GRUB menu. You can choose an older kernel to boot into from the recovery options menu item.

**Install 3.19 Kernel**

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`

The above command will install the [backported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) 3.19 kernel from the LTS Enablement Stack. You may have more luck with that one. It installed flawlessly for me in any case. See [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/82/137) answer for instructions for installing other kernel versions.

**Troubleshooting**

Alternatively you could boot to a recovery mode console (from GRUB) and examine your [logs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) for clues as to why it is stalling on boot. Especially the following...

`less /var/log/kern.log` (Shows Kernel messages)

`less /var/log/Xorg.0.log` (X server logs)

`less /var/log/syslog` (Overarching system log)

Comment: This worked! Actually it was installed as dependency from linux-image-3.19...but somehow that way didn't work. However installing that package instead (purge, then go only for linux-generic-lts-vivid, which apparently pulled as dependency linux-image-3.19) somehow worked better. Booted to login then to desktop with no issues. And the root issue seems solved, seems my fans are working!

Thanks!

Comment: Win/Win ;p Good to hear.